# Cypher query : Selecting branches without missing parts

Tags: collections, neo4j, filtering, cypher

I'm new to Cypher and am struggling to do a basic filter.

Given the following model I would like to only retrieve "d2".

```
a1-
 | \c1
 | /  \
b1-    \d1
       /
a2-   /
   \c2
   /  
b2-    

a3-
 | \c3--d2
 | /  
b3-
```

I saw things to identify the missing part :

`(match (a)--(c)--(d) WHERE NOT (a)--(b)--(c) return d)`

which gives me "d1".

How can I do `WHERE ALL (a)--(b)`, or remove a set of nodes from above query (d1) from a given list (d1, d2)?

Answer (score 0):

Found what I think is a dirty way (guess performance would be crappy) but does the trick :

```
match (a)--(c)--(b), (c)--(d)
where not (a)--(b)
with collect(d) as excluded
match (a)--(c)--(b)--(a), (c)--(d)
where NOT d IN excluded
return d;
```

Any better idea would be great :-)